# Internationalisation in Android application using Xamarin and the MvvmCross framework

Tags: android, internationalization, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'am trying to implement internationalisation in my Xamarin application based on the MvvmCross framework. To do that, I follow the Stuart's video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkxHtbJ_Tlk&feature=youtube_gdata

My problem is when i try to use one of the resource I put in my JSON file, the good string is not returned.

For example, I have a JSON file ListCustomersViewModel.json in the Assets/InternationalisationResources/Text folder of my Android application which contains :

```
{
"MyTitle":"Titre de la page"
}
```

So in order to make a link with my TextView, I put this code in the AXML file ListCustomersView.axml :

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        local:MvxLang="Text MyTitle"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
```

But instead of displaying the string "Titre de la page", my application displays "Xamarin.Client|ListCustomersViewModel|MyTitle". "Xamarin.Client" is the value I gave to my GeneralNamespace.

I don't understand the source of the problem. I followed all the steps described by Stuart Lodge but I suppose I missed something.

If you have any idea...

Comment: Check everything about your JSON resource files - name, location, build action, etc - compare them against a sample that works

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer.
So I compared JSON resource files between the Babel project and mine.
The name of my JSON file seems good, as the location.
There was one main difference however : the build action of my JSON file which was "None". So I put the build action to "Content" thinking that would solve my problem but it doesn't.
It's like the file wasn't found or parsed...

Comment: Ok so the build action was a part of the solution. In fact, I had added the ResourceLoader and the JsonLocalisation plugins but I needed also the Json Plugin. Now it works perfectly. I thank you for your help Stuart ;)